# Question on directional derivatives

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Suppose a function f: $R^2 \rightarrow R$ is defined by $\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^4}$ if x,y is non zero, and f(x,y) = 0 if (x,y)=(0,0). Show that for all unit vectors u the directional derivative
of f at the origin in the direction u does exist,
but f is discontinuous at (0, 0). Show that there is no
plane which contains all the lines which are tangent
to the surface z = f(x, y) at (0, 0, 0).

Comments: 
1. For the first part, I am approaching this by trying to prove that the function satisfies the definition of differentiability, namely that there exists a linear map L such that $\frac{||f(x)-f(0,0)-L(x-(0,0))||}{||x||}$ as x->0 is 0. So I got that the Jacobian was a zero matrix, so we just get $\frac{xy^2}{(x^2+y^4) \sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ but I don't think this goes to zero? Have I made a mistake somewhere? I am aware that there are other ways to prove differentiability (such as using the fact that if partials exist and are continuous), but why is this way not getting me the answer?

2. Could someone help me with the part about showing there's no plane? Would it be along the lines of showing that there's no single normal vector common to all the derivative vectors at (0,0)?

Comment: There must be some problem with this as the directional derivative is $df(a,b)=0$ which is linear, that is all the tangents lie on a plane, in this case the $x,y$ plane.

Comment: Viewed 9 times with 2 downvotes, shows the state of this site.

Comment: So why are there down votes? Is it because the question is wrong? 
Also, are you saying that the directional derivative is always zero? Or ?

Comment: Dont know why the downvotes, resentment ?,arrogance ? Superiority ? Anyway, yeah I think the directional derivatives are all zero. Which means all the tangent vectors have slope $0$, so there is a well defined tangent plane, but it does not approximate the function in the sense of a multivariable limit.

Comment: @amd how do you know that all the directional derivatives exist?

Comment: Use the fundamental definition of the directional derivative as the limit of the difference quotient taken along a specific ray.

Comment: Is it possible for a function to have directional derivatives in any direction, but for it to not satisfy the definition of differentiability?

Comment: Certainly. Directional derivatives only “look” along straight lines, but for differentiability (and continuity) you have to get consistent results along *all* paths to the point. This function isn’t even continuous at the origin, so can’t be differentiable.

Comment: I’d previously left a factor out of the denominator when I computed the derivatives, so I retract my initial comment about them. They exist, but they’re not all zero and are inconsistent.

Comment: @amd I get they are zero, I could have made a mistake, what nonzero value do you get ?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus I got zero, too, but I’d forgotten to divide by the displacement. For $u=(a,b)$ with $a\ne0$, the limit of the difference quotient is $b^2/a$.

Comment: @amd you are right, I forgot the same thing.  Well, them the directional derivative is $b^2/a$ which is not linear, so the tangent lines are not on the same plane , as the question says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let’s start with continuity. For $f$ to be continuous at the origin, its limit along *every* path to the origin must be equal to its value there. Consider the curve $x=y^2$: $$\lim_{y\to0}f(y^2,y) = \lim_{y\to0}{y^4\over2y^4} = \frac12 \ne f(0,0).$$ Since $f$ is not continuous at the origin, it’s not differentiable, either.

On the other hand, let $u=(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ for fixed $\theta$. The derivative in the direction of $u$ is $$\begin{align} \lim_{h\to0^+}\frac1h \left[f(h\cos\theta,h\sin\theta)-f(0,0)\right] &= \lim_{h\to0^+}\frac1h{(h\cos\theta)(h\sin\theta)^2 \over (h\cos\theta)^2+(h\sin\theta)^4} \\
&= \lim_{h\to0^+}{\cos\theta \sin^2\theta \over \cos^2\theta + h^2\sin^4\theta} \\
&= {\sin^2\theta\over\cos\theta} \end{align}$$ if $\cos\theta\ne0$, which corresponds to derivatives in the direction of the $y$-axis. For those cases $f(0,y)=0$, so the directional derivative, which is just $f_y(0,0)$, is equal to $0$. We also have $f(x,0)=0$, so $f_x(0,0)=0$, therefore if there were a tangent plane, it would have to be the $x$-$y$ plane. This means that all directional derivatives must vanish, but there are clearly values of $\theta$ for which they are non-zero.

Comment: I’ll add that the partial derivatives of $f$ are also continuous at the origin. Don’t forget to check that $f$ itself is continuous when determining differentiability!